# Display javascript date genererator in submit form

Tags: javascript, forms

This code is giving output correctly in button type but not in input type. I just want to display the month and year in Submit form.

```
<input type="submit" id="demo" value="Submit form">
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function getDate() {
        var month_name = new Array("January", "February", "March", 
                                    "April", "May", "June", "July",
                                    "August", "September", "October",
                                    "November", "December"
                             );

        var date = new Date();
        var curr_month = date.getMonth();
        var curr_year = date.getFullYear();
        document.write(month_name[curr_month] + "," + curr_year);

    }
</script>
```

Comment: where you are calling your getDate() function

Comment: did you do onclick method in <input type="submit" id="demo" value="Submit form" onclick="getDate();">

Answer (score 2):

js

```
    function getDate() {
    var month_name = new Array("January", "February", "March",
        "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September",
        "October", "November", "December");
    var date = new Date();
    var curr_month = date.getMonth();
    var curr_year = date.getFullYear();
    var input = document.getElementById("demo");
    input.value = month_name[curr_month] + "," + curr_year;
}
```

html - or if you want to click it and getDate() put it as `onclick="getDate()"` within the `<input>` html tag

```
 <body onload="getDate()">
    <input type="submit" id="demo" value="Submit form">
</body>
```

demo
http://jsfiddle.net/z26mevsv/

Answer (score 1):

this will allso help you

```
<input type="submit" id="demo" value="Submit form" onclick="getDate();">
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function getDate() {
        var month_name = new Array("January", "February", "March","April", "May", "June","July", "August", "September","October", "November", "December");
        var date = new Date();
        var curr_month = date.getMonth();
        var curr_year = date.getFullYear();
        document.write(month_name[curr_month] + "," + curr_year);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

so in order to display the value there, you need to get the input element.  You have the `id="demo"`, and that is the best way to reference that element.  try out the following code:

```
<input type="submit" id="demo" value="Submit form">
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function getDate() {
        var month_name = new Array("January", "February", "March","April", "May", "June","July", "August", "September","October", "November", "December");
        var date = new Date();
        var curr_month = date.getMonth();
        var curr_year = date.getFullYear();
        document.getElementById('demo').value = month_name[curr_month] + "," + curr_year;
    }
    window.onload = function(){
        getDate();
    }
</script>
```

of course you need to call your function `getDate()` from somewhere, so I called that in the `onload()` function.